# minio command cannot be found after deploy

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, minio

I created a docker-compose file to use s3. the file is a follows:

```
version: "3"
services:

  s3:
    image: "docker.example.com/minio/minio:latest"
    restart: always
    networks:
      local:
    ports:
      - "${s3port}:8080"
    volumes:
      - s3:/data
    entrypoint: sh
    command: "-c 'mkdir -p /data/proj && /usr/bin/minio server /data'"
    env_file:
      - ./conf/env.s3
networks:
  local:

volumes:
  s3:
```

after that the container restarts continuesly and it says:

> /usr/bin/minio: no such file or directory

I think it belongs to path permissions.
has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `minio` binary is not at `/usr/bin/minio`. Please use the official minio image:

```
version: "3"
services:

  s3:
    image: "minio/minio"
    restart: always
    networks:
      local:
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - s3:/data
    command: "server --console-address :9001 /data"
    env_file:
      - ./conf/env.s3
networks:
  local:

volumes:
  s3:
```

With this, you should be able to use the browser UI at http://localhost:9001 and the S3 endpoint at http://localhost:9000

Learn more at https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-docker-quickstart-guide

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.